# Automatically View size is increasing in appcelarator titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am building an app in which I am using `scrollView` with 'scrollableview'. When scrolling the image, the view size is automatic increasing.

If I am giving the height in `px` then it is working fine but when I am giving height in `%` this code is not working fine. but, I need height in `%` only.

Here is my code:

```js
 
var imageCollection = [
"/images/offers/oneplusOffer.jpg",
 "images/offers/electronicsOffer.jpg",
  "images/offers/shoesOffer.jpg", 
  "images/offers/watchOffer.jpg"
  ];
  
  var viewCollection = [];
  
 // Vertical ScrollBar
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    top:0,
    left:0,
    backgroundColor:'#f1f1f1',
   
    layout:'vertical'
});
 
 // offerBanner view
var bannerView=Ti.UI.createView({
 height:"10%",
 backgroundColor:"pink",

});

 for (var i = 0; i < imageCollection.length; i++) {
 var view = Ti.UI.createView({
  backgroundColor: 'yellow'
 });

 
 var img = Ti.UI.createImageView({
   
   image : imageCollection[i]
  });
  view.add(img);
 
 viewCollection.push(view);
}

var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    top:0,
   views:viewCollection,
    showPagingControl:false,
});

bannerView.add(scrollableView);
scrollView.add(bannerView);



//creating view

for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
var view=Ti.UI.createView({
 
 top:"2%",
 backgroundColor:"blue",
 //height:"120",
 height:"15%",
});

//adding view to scrollview
scrollView.add(view);

}



$.homeScreenWindow.add(scrollView);
$.homeScreenWindow.open();
```

Comment: can you show an image with the layout you are trying to achieve? Both versions look almost the same for me (just that 15% is bigger as 120px on my phone). Which OS and which SDK are you using?

Comment: @Ashish, you need to give more learning time on how layout stuff works along with percentage in different view types. Since ScrollView is the view which doesn't have a definite height for children, hence using %age for child views in ScrollView is not the recommended way. So you should calculate the 15% height in dp before creating those views & it will work on all devices.

Comment: @Ashish, since you are giving views a height of 15%, then you must know that 15% of what?. Therefore as you know 15% of what, you can simply convert it into dp or pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    top:0,
    left:0,
    backgroundColor:'#f1f1f1',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    layout:'vertical'
});
```

you can also give the above `height` in `%` as well. Try this.